# Simplexml - белый экран

Tags: php

**У меня есть вот такой код:**

`$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://****.ru/?format=feed&type=rss');
echo $xml->title;`

**И вот такой `var_dump($xml)`:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=>
string(3) "2.0" } ["channel"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) { ["image"]=>
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["url"]=> string(22) "http://*/img.jpg" }
["item"]=> array(20) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (6) { ["title"]=>
string(12) "Smart Search" ["link"]=> string(48) "http://**/index.php/item/70-smart-search"
["description"]=> string(21) " ..." ["image_item"]=> string(98)
"/var/www/user36565/data/www/*.ru/media/k2/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_L.jpg"
["category"]=> string(15) "Utility Modules" ["pubDate"]=> 
string(31) "Tue, 17 Jan 2012 03:42:36 +0000" } [1]=> 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (6) { ["title"]=> string(11) "Quick Icons" ["link"]=> 
string(47) "http://*.ru/index.php/item/69-quick-icons" ["descrip.............
```

**Но в итоге команда `echo $xml->title;` показывает просто белый экран**

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Лучше выложите кусок xml, который вы хотите распарсить.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">  
<channel>
    <image>
     <url>http://*ru/img.jpg</url>
    </image>
    <item>
 <title>Smart Search</title>
 <link>http://*.ru/index.php/item/70-smart-search</link>
 <description>     ...</description>
 <image_item>/var/www/user36565/data/www/*.ru/media/k2/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_L.jpg</image_item>
 <category>Utility Modules</category>
 <pubDate>Tue, 17 Jan 2012 03:42:36 +0000</pubDate>
 <yandex:full-text></yandex:full-text></item

Comment: Нашел вот, что проблема непонятным @attributes:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/64464/php-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xml-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-params

Но как сделать не пойму

Comment: Или не с ним

Comment: а так  $xml->channel->title ?

Comment: $xml->channel->title пустой экран

Comment: ответил ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/4vMIx9
Если элементов много, то `foreach` поможет цикл по ним сделать и вывести